# Recommend SQL database backup for db size 1TB

Tags: sql-server, backup

Currently, our NAV 2013 database has been growing. It takes about 1TB now and is running on SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

We would like to check if there any best practice for backup up a database backup of this size.

Answer (score 6):

There are no absolute recommendations we can give you with the information you've given.

Things this depends on:

- Your current backup settings. In SQL 2008 R2 you can [compress backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-compression-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to save on backup size. You should also consider upgrading to SQL Server 2012 ([which seems to be supported on NAV 2013](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/erpsoftwareblog/posts/microsoft-dynamics-nav-2013-system-requirements)).
- Server performance (CPU/IO): How long does it take the server to perform a full backup, if your storage is fast, 1TB full backup time can be reasonable. If you have the CPU to spare, compressing shouldn't be an issue either.
- Maintenance window: If you have the window to perform a full backup every day, it's the easiest option. You can add incremental backups to the mix and go for a weekly full backup and a daily incremental backup, but that could possibly add to your recovery time.
- RTO/RPO: How many and which types of backups you take should be dictated by the business and not something somebody wrote on the internet as a "best practice". How often do you need transaction log backups? How fast do you need to be able to recover in the event of a disaster?

If you decide to go for a more complex combination of backup types because your server, maintenance windows and RTO/RPO dictate it, be sure to script out and test restores, because if you are going to have to use the SSMS UI to select the correct files and restore them in order you are going to spend a lot of time recovering.